# There is no script tag when an app is created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I ran the command `npx create-react-app app-name` the usual template got created. But when I checked into the html file, I found no script tag inside of it. But when I run `npm start` the app runs fine and the JS script gets executed.

I am not sure what is going on behind the scenes. I tried looking into other apps, but I found the same thing. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The script is likely added during the build step.

Comment: I have the same issue after updating my version of node, npm, yarn etc, & also all packages e.g. react, react-scripts etc.